# Couldn't connect to GitHub while authenicating to github on heroku

Tags: heroku, github-actions

I had created a app on heroku on **while authenticating to github it say**

```
Error: remote was closed, authorization was denied, or an authentication message otherwise not received before the window closed..
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: I'm getting the same error https://prnt.sc/tmrm3f

Answer (score 9):

I was also facing the same error in Google Chrome.

> Error: remote was closed, authorization was denied, or an authentication message otherwise not received before the window closed.`

I tried opening in Chrome's Incognito mode and it worked for me.

Again, I tried using Firefox and it also worked!

Comment: If it works in a different browser and in Incognito mode, is it possible this is a cookie issue? E.g., could this be fixed simply by clearing the cookies?

Answer (score 4):

I guess it's for pushing an app on heroku, so if it's that you can use a action on the GitHub marketplace to do so :
You have this one :  [heroku deploy](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-to-heroku)

You will have to set you heroku key in secrets on repository settings before and set your workflow just like this:

```yaml
name: Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: akhileshns/heroku-deploy@v3.0.4 # This is the action
        with:
          heroku_api_key: ${{secrets.HEROKU_API_KEY}}
          heroku_app_name: "YOUR APP's NAME" #Must be unique in Heroku
          heroku_email: "YOUR EMAIL"
          buildpack: "SOME BUILDPACK" #OPTIONAL
          branch: "YOUR_BRANCH" #OPTIONAL and DEFAULT - 'HEAD' (a.k.a your current branch)
          dontuseforce: false #OPTIONAL and DEFAULT - false
          usedocker: false #OPTIONAL and DEFAULT - false
          appdir: "" #OPTIONAL and DEFAULT - "". This is useful if the api you're deploying is in a subfolder
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: hello, I put that on workflow but still when I want to connect github with heroku I got an error

Comment: Which error did you have?

Comment: I fix it ...that was my mistake ...thank you so much your answer really helped me and I already deploy my code using it